# error connecting to quickblox chat api from android app

Tags: android, android-intent, quickblox

I am new to stackoverflow as well as android development. I am trying to connect to quickblox chat api through another android application.Below is the code.I am unable to connect and getting error - `"User id and password null":`

**Java code :**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx");

        ///new code for quickblox
        QBAuth.createSession(new QBUser("username", "password"), new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession session, Bundle params) {
                QBChatService chatService;

                if (!QBChatService.isInitialized()) {
                    QBChatService.init(getApplicationContext());
                    chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
                } else {
                    QBChatService.init(getApplicationContext());
                    chatService = QBChatService.getInstance();
                }

                final QBUser user = new QBUser("username", "password");
                chatService.login(user, new QBEntityCallbackImpl() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(List errors) {
                        // errror
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                // errors
            }
        });
```